# Android app to communicate with server hosted by a particular device.

Tags: android, json, client-server, android-volley, tcp

How to request and retrieve data (in JSON format) from a server AP hosted by a device (say ESP-WROOM-02 module) in our custom android application, using TCP/IP sockets? Is Volley a suitable android networking library to use for this purpose? Please suggest some ways to start with this project.

Comment: You can use libraries like Volley / Retrofit for this. Retrofit is better compared to Volley.

Comment: Do you have an endpoint configured which will serve you the json you need? If so, there are various options like retrofit, okhttp, volley, async (in descending order of my preference), which you can use to get the data.

Comment: Does that take care of the JSON parsing part?